# Is payment processing fee (paid by customer) interest if that fee become a gain for me instead of cost?

Tags: riba, business

I take occasional payment from my customers using bKash (a mobile financial service provider in Bangladesh). I'm using their personal account option, which is mainly for personal transaction. I load money (called cash in), do mobile topup, make online payment and send money to other bKash users. All of the services are free of cost, except send money.

When I need cash, I do cash out from their agents and the fee costs nearly 2% of the amount cashed.

So, when I accept payment from my customers in this personal account, I ask for 2% extra, since cash out incurs a 2% cost on me. But if I make online payment/mobile top-up with the amount received from my customers, that 2% becomes my gain.

**From an Islamic view point, will this extra 2% be considered as interest (Riba) on my part?**

*Note: I had to completely rewrite the questions to clear many confusions.*

Comment: Can you elaborate on the method "X" and if you mean that the third party providing this service gives some some discount or cashback which you count as 'gain'?

Comment: @Ahmed, I've edited the question. The fee that I take from customer will be deducted from my account only if I take the money out of the payment company wallet. This is not a traditional merchant account, rather I'm using my personal account to take occasional payment. Hope its less confusing now.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, I've taken the tour. Thanks for referring. The Fee is imposed by me. Please see the [comment](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47182/is-payment-processing-fee-paid-by-customer-interest-if-that-fee-become-a-gain#comment80399_47182).

Comment: I assume you are charging the customer because the third party is charging you a transaction fee and you are passing it on to the customer as part of your cost price. If so a related Fatwa: http://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa-87581/info  But if the third party is not charging you a fee, is the end customer aware that is a convenience fee that you charge and goes into your pocket?

Comment: @Ahmed, I've re-wrote the question. Please do have a look.

Comment: @NezamUddin Excellent!  Looks clear to me.

Comment: Interest is a function of time. What you are describing is transaction cost. So you are paying for the company to use its electronic systems. You are not paying for time.

Comment: @TheZ, I'm not sure if Riba is only a function of time. There is a type of Riba named Riba al fadl, which arises while exchanging similar type of goods but of different quality.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to understand the complete payment method.

As I know, when we accept payment by credit card and PayPal they charge 2-4% service charge (depending on the country).

So if I sell my item at $200 and the user pays by cash I will get the complete $200.

If the user pays by credit card or PayPal, I have to pay $4 (for 2%) to the company. In this case I will be in loss, so I ask the customer to pay that 2% because I cannot bear my loss.

In this case nothing is wrong and it will not be considered as INTEREST.